# HTTP ERROR 502 on uploading wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress, plugins

First i have installed and activated the moderator plugin on wordpress and it was working perfectly for about a week and then i remove and deactivate that plugin and try to reinstall the same plugin but it gives me "HTTP ERROR 502" error.

What went wrong after one week with that downloaded plugin ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Causes of the 502 Bad Gateway Error**

Most times, this error happens when there’s poor communication between your servers, something you clearly have no control over.

However, this error can happen due to a number of reasons such as:

- One/all of your upstream servers are down or can’t be accessed
- Your server is simply overloaded
- You have buggy PHP scripts such as faulty WordPress plugins or themes
- Browser cache is acting up
- Problems with your router or networking equipment
- Your content delivery network (CDN) is acting up
- You have domain name system (DNS) issues

Comment: All other things like frontend and dashboard are working normally but when i try to upload/install this plugin then it give that error.

Comment: Also more interesting thing is that when i try to install that plugin on local computer it works fine.

Comment: On local there is no error. plugin installed, activated and running perfectly, but on live it gives error.

Comment: Might be error is regarding a path may I know a plugin name.

Comment: I have made that plugin. It is not live.

Comment: Do one thing make wp_debug true and check if any error if not then check might be space or something is there.